# Apper won't run anymore

Tags: kde

I set up my newly installed system and at one point Apper was gone. I could not start it anymore. Unfortunately I am not sure what I did before it happened.
I was installing rkhunter and Clamtk but don't think that caused the problem.

My first error was:

> KDEInit could not launch '/usr/bin/apper'

I then reinstalled apper via sudo apt-get apper and receive the following bug report:

> Executable: apper PID: 2308 Signal: Segmentation fault (11) Time:

Developer Information:

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ff7bc57d940 (LWP 2380)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  0x00007ff7c4ec30ca in KCModuleProxy::realModule() const () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KCMUtils.so.5
#7  0x00005607b07b99a6 in MainUi::MainUi(QWidget*) ()
#8  0x00005607b07be1b7 in Apper::showUi() ()
#9  0x00007ff7c1c64072 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007ff7c257e1a4 in QGuiApplication::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#11 0x00007ff7c33ae01f in QApplication::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#12 0x00007ff7c33a84c1 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#13 0x00007ff7c33af970 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#14 0x00007ff7c1c3a489 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007ff7c1c3d46b in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#16 0x00007ff7c1c8c103 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#17 0x00007ff7c2ec6f2e in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007ff7c2ec71c8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007ff7c2ec725c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ff7c1c8b727 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#21 0x00007ff7bc1d4401 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#22 0x00007ff7c1c3915b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x00007ff7c1c41132 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#24 0x00005607b07b93e7 in main ()
[Inferior 1 (process 2380) detached]
```

Thanks and sorry for asking so many questions but I am determined to learn but could not find anything on Google re this error

Answer (score 0):

Discover asked for updates for apper and that resolved the issue after a reboot.